# Path of kerberos tickets TGT and service tickets in windows XP and unix?

Tags: windows, unix, authentication, kerberos, windowsdomainaccount

Could someone please send across the path of kerberos tickets TGT and service tickets in windows XP and unix?

Also, how do we know the version of kerberos being used in windows and unix?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [klist](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-user/Viewing-Your-Tickets-with-klist.html) to get the Kerberos tickets on Unix.  The ticket path is different from OS to OS.  The klist command should tell you the path.  On some Unix platforms, you can specify -4 or -5 to just show the v4 tickets or v5 tickets.

You can use [Kerbtray](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=4E3A58BE-29F6-49F6-85BE-E866AF8E7A88&displaylang=en) or Klist to see the details of kerberos ticket on Windows XP.  Both of them can be found from [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en).  Actually, you should always have v5 kerberos tickets if your Windows is joined to Active Directory.

If you don't have permission to install Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit on your Windows XP machine, try to google "tktview".  It's a tool written by Keith Brown long time ago. The source code was included in one of the MSDN articles back to the year 2000

Comment: I could use klist to see service tickets on my unix machine, but I don't have permission to install anything on my windows xp machine, so is there any inbuilt way to see the list of service tickets without needing to install anything.?

Comment: @learnforever You need to install Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit to get Kerbtray. It actually also contains another KList. If you are not allowed to install anything on your XP, I would suggest that you install it on a machine that you do have permission to install and then simply copy it over. There is another alternative. It's tktview written by Keith Brown long time ago. The source code is included as one of the MSDN articles sample back to the year 2000. I have a local copy. If you need, I can email you.